# Is postgres byte array escaping broken in ruby?

Tags: ruby, postgresql

Easy example:

```
Zlib::Inflate.inflate(PG::Connection.unescape_bytea(PG::Connection.escape_bytea(Zlib::Deflate.deflate('["128,491,128,487"]'))))
Zlib::DataError: incorrect data check
```

This is not issue with zlib because following succeeds:

```
Zlib::Inflate.inflate(Zlib::Deflate.deflate('["128,491,128,487"]'))
=> "[\"128,491,128,487\"]"
```

Parsing fails/succeeds dependant on provided string:

```
Zlib::Inflate.inflate(PG::Connection.unescape_bytea(PG::Connection.escape_bytea(Zlib::Deflate.deflate('["128,491,128,487", "128,491,128,490", "38,465,40,463"]'))))
=> "[\"128,491,128,487\", \"128,491,128,490\", \"38,465,40,463\"]"
```

Am i doing something wrong or is postgres bytea field escaping in ruby broken? What can i do as alternative?

Tried on: Ruby 2.2.3p173, gem pg-0.18.4; Ruby 2.4.1p111, gem pg-0.21.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer from https://bitbucket.org/ged/ruby-pg/issues/262/postgres-bytearray-escaping :

The description of (un)escape_bytea is misleading. It's not the exact opposite of each other.

PG::Connection.escape_bytea uses the old and deprecated escaping mechanism, which must be double escaped - first as a BYTEA and secondary as a string literal (per adding ' before and after the string) for insertion into the SQL string. This is done in one step for convenience and performance reasons.

On contrary PG::Connection.unescape_bytea does only BYTEA unescaping, because it is meant to decode column data retrieved by a query. This data is not escaped as a string literal.
You now have two options to make the above work:

```
enco = PG::TextEncoder::Bytea.new
deco = PG::TextDecoder::Bytea.new
Zlib::Inflate.inflate(deco.decode(enco.encode(Zlib::Deflate.deflate('["128,491,128,487"]'))))
```

This makes use of the type encoders of the pg gem instead of libpq. The encoder uses the newer BYTEA escaping machanism and is a bit faster than libpq's functions. This is still independent of a server connection.
conn = PG.connect

```
Zlib::Inflate.inflate(conn.unescape_bytea(conn.escape_bytea(Zlib::Deflate.deflate('["128,491,128,487"]'))))
```

This makes use of the connection bound escaping functions of libpq. They also use the newer escaping mechanism, so that no double escaping occurs.